# Subquery works efficiently until I add order by and limit

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Sorry I'm new to `SQL` and this question is for `PostgreSQL` specifically.
I am trying to subset one table by the top 30 results. And then join data from another table based on those top 30 results.

I have the following two tables:

[image: portfolio has 500k entries and portfolio_res has 1.7 billion entries]

```
                             Table "public.portfolio"
       Column        |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default
---------------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 portfolio_id        | bigint  |           | not null | generated always as identity
 sample_space_id     | bigint  |           | not null |
 sample_space_idx    | bigint  |           | not null |
 backtest_id         | bigint  |           | not null |
 above_threshold     | boolean |           | not null |
 opt_allocation      | integer |           | not null |
 end_portfolio_value | numeric |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "portfolio_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (portfolio_id)
    "portfolio_un" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (sample_space_idx, sample_space_id, backtest_id, opt_allocation)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "portfolio_fk_backtest" FOREIGN KEY (backtest_id) REFERENCES backtest(backtest_id)
    "portfolio_fk_samplespace_spyoptions" FOREIGN KEY (sample_space_idx, sample_space_id) REFERENCES sample_space_spy_options(sample_space_idx, sample_space_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "portfolio_res" CONSTRAINT "portfolio_res_fk" FOREIGN KEY (portfolio_id) REFERENCES portfolio(portfolio_id)

                             Table "public.portfolio_res"
      Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |             Default
------------------+---------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------
 sample_space_idx | bigint  |           | not null |
 opt_allocation   | integer |           | not null |
 sample_space_id  | bigint  |           | not null |
 portfolio_return | numeric |           | not null |
 portfolio_value  | numeric |           | not null |
 date             | date    |           | not null |
 backtest_id      | bigint  |           | not null |
 portfolio_id     | bigint  |           | not null | generated by default as identity
 portfolio_res_id | bigint  |           | not null | generated by default as identity
Indexes:
    "portfolio_res_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (portfolio_res_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "portfolio_res_fk" FOREIGN KEY (portfolio_id) REFERENCES portfolio(portfolio_id)
```

portfolio has 500k entries and portfolio_res has 1.7 billion entries.

`portfolio_res` is `FK` to `portfolio` by `portfolio_id`

I have tried the following query and it executes quickly.

```
explain analyze
select
        pr.*
from    portfolio_res pr
where   pr.portfolio_id in (
    select  p.portfolio_id 
    from    portfolio p
    where   p.above_threshold and 
            p.backtest_id = 1 and
            p.end_portfolio_value > 2   
    --order by p.end_portfolio_value desc
    --limit 30
)   
limit 100;

Limit  (cost=0.42..2552.87 rows=100 width=72) (actual time=1.434..1.751 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..9028780082.16 rows=353730719 width=72) (actual time=1.433..1.745 rows=100 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on portfolio_res pr  (cost=0.00..25752363.36 rows=1103723136 width=72) (actual time=0.010..0.053 rows=591 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using portfolio_pk on portfolio p  (cost=0.42..8.16 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=591)
              Index Cond: (portfolio_id = pr.portfolio_id)
              Filter: (above_threshold AND (end_portfolio_value > '2'::numeric) AND (backtest_id = 1))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.179 ms
Execution Time: 1.768 ms
```

when i uncomment the commented lines ( I am trying to select the top 30 ordered by `end_portfolio_value` ), the query takes forever. Here is the explain output:

```
explain analyze
select
        pr.*
from    portfolio_res pr
where   pr.portfolio_id in (
    select  p.portfolio_id 
    from    portfolio p
    where   p.above_threshold and 
            p.backtest_id = 1 and
            p.end_portfolio_value > 2   
    order by p.end_portfolio_value desc
    limit 30
)   
limit 100;

Limit  (cost=10068.43..12586.01 rows=100 width=72)
  ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=10068.43..28672370.67 rows=1138485 width=72)
        Hash Cond: (pr.portfolio_id = "ANY_subquery".portfolio_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on portfolio_res pr  (cost=0.00..25752363.36 rows=1103723136 width=72)
        ->  Hash  (cost=10068.06..10068.06 rows=30 width=8)
              ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=10064.26..10068.06 rows=30 width=8)
                    ->  Limit  (cost=10064.26..10067.76 rows=30 width=20)
                          ->  Gather Merge  (cost=10064.26..23838.88 rows=118060 width=20)
                                Workers Planned: 2
                                ->  Sort  (cost=9064.23..9211.81 rows=59030 width=20)
                                      Sort Key: p.end_portfolio_value DESC
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on portfolio p  (cost=0.00..7320.81 rows=59030 width=20)
                                            Filter: (above_threshold AND (end_portfolio_value > '2'::numeric) AND (backtest_id = 1))
```

Am I misunderstanding how `subqueries` work? If I run the `subquery` on its own, its very fast as well:

```
explain analyze
select  p.portfolio_id 
from    portfolio p
where   p.above_threshold and 
        p.backtest_id = 1 and
        p.end_portfolio_value > 2   
order by p.end_portfolio_value desc
limit 30;

Limit  (cost=10064.26..10067.76 rows=30 width=20) (actual time=54.794..66.802 rows=30 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=10064.26..23838.88 rows=118060 width=20) (actual time=54.793..66.798 rows=30 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=9064.23..9211.81 rows=59030 width=20) (actual time=41.615..41.616 rows=24 loops=3)
              Sort Key: end_portfolio_value DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on portfolio p  (cost=0.00..7320.81 rows=59030 width=20) (actual time=0.042..35.259 rows=47630 loops=3)
                    Filter: (above_threshold AND (end_portfolio_value > '2'::numeric) AND (backtest_id = 1))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 99720
Planning Time: 0.119 ms
Execution Time: 66.822 ms
```

The `subquery` by itself returns `30` values as by the `limit`. And I just want to subset the `1.7 billion` rows from `portfolio_res` based on those `30 portfolio_ids`

I have also tried using `joins` instead of `subqueries` and the results are also slow when I add the `order by end_portfolio_value`. I'll include those just in case I'm doing something wrong.

```
explain analyze
with subquery as (
    select  portfolio_id 
    from    portfolio p
    where   above_threshold and 
            backtest_id = 1 and
            end_portfolio_value > 2
    -- too slow if i include these
    --order by end_portfolio_value desc
    --limit 30
)

select  pr.*
from    subquery
left join portfolio_res pr
    on pr.portfolio_id = subquery.portfolio_id
limit 100;

Limit  (cost=16347.09..16712.65 rows=100 width=72) (actual time=1436.510..1436.538 rows=100 loops=1)
  CTE subquery
    ->  Seq Scan on portfolio p  (cost=0.00..11188.75 rows=141672 width=8) (actual time=112.617..1117.230 rows=142889 loops=1)
          Filter: (above_threshold AND (end_portfolio_value > '2'::numeric) AND (backtest_id = 1))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 299161
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=5158.34..19653706789.88 rows=5376380970 width=72) (actual time=1436.509..1436.533 rows=100 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (pr.portfolio_id = subquery.portfolio_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on portfolio_res pr  (cost=0.00..25752363.36 rows=1103723136 width=72) (actual time=40.925..262.089 rows=79243 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=2833.44..2833.44 rows=141672 width=8) (actual time=1158.827..1158.827 rows=142889 loops=1)
              Buckets: 131072  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 3809kB
              ->  CTE Scan on subquery  (cost=0.00..2833.44 rows=141672 width=8) (actual time=112.621..1145.698 rows=142889 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.167 ms
Execution Time: 1713.112 ms
```

```
explain analyze
select 
            pr.*
from        portfolio_res pr 
left join   portfolio p 
    on  p.portfolio_id = pr.portfolio_id 
where   pr.backtest_id = 1 and
        p.above_threshold and
        p.end_portfolio_value > 2
--order by p.end_portfolio_value desc
limit 100;

Limit  (cost=0.42..2552.87 rows=100 width=72) (actual time=1767.299..1767.598 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..9028780088.40 rows=353730719 width=72) (actual time=1767.298..1767.580 rows=100 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on portfolio_res pr  (cost=0.00..28511671.20 rows=1103723136 width=72) (actual time=0.014..133.253 rows=596055 loops=1)
              Filter: (backtest_id = 1)
        ->  Index Scan using portfolio_pk on portfolio p  (cost=0.42..8.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=596055)
              Index Cond: (portfolio_id = pr.portfolio_id)
              Filter: (above_threshold AND (end_portfolio_value > '2'::numeric))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.196 ms
Execution Time: 1767.632 ms
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am fairly new to `SQL` and `PostgreSQL` so I may be thinking or doing this entirely wrong.

Comment: where   p.above_threshold and   Sorry, but it looks suspicious

Comment: @Sergey suspicious?

Comment: Yes. I expect something like where   p.above_threshold = 1    and

Comment: @Sergey that field is bool

Comment: You don't have a good index in place to satisfy the correlated sub-query.  Create a single index on `portfolio` for `above_threshold, backtest_id, end_portfolio_value` *(in that order)* and possibly include `portfolio_id`.  Also, consider whether the table statistics are out of date, research use of `ANALYZE` to check options *(I'm no postgresql expert, so won't make any recommendations there)*.

Comment: "with subquery as ( ..."  cte example ,why did you use right join? i think there should be left join.

Comment: @MatBailie should I create the sub-query on `portfolio_res` or `portfolio` ? I feel like the query is slow because `portfolio_res` can't filter `where pr.portfolio_id = MY_SUBSET` very well

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy yes, it should be. Also very slow. Will include left join instead of right join shortly

Comment: Is there an index on portfolio_res.portfolio_id? if there is no index then planer has no choice but to do full seq scan to filter all necessary rows. If there is an index, and its still slow, there might several reasons i am thinking- poor table statistics or incorrect or bloated table/index. Foreign key is alone is not enough.

Comment: Index on portfolio_id is not "optional", it's really necessary to improve this query run speed and overall server performance if this query is run often. Keep in mind that in some other databases when creating foreign keys, an index is created on those columns too, so separate index is not necessary there. But that's not the case with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the DBMS is free to choose the execution plan that it finds most promising. When writing the query, we don't know whether the DBMS will first select all rows in the subquery and then base the main query on that or read the main query rows instead and check whether it has a match in the subquery. These are two very different approaches and can result in very different execution times. (The resulting rows will be the same, of course.)

It seems that the DBMS decided for the looping approach with the first query, and obviously it is quick to loop through the portfolio_res table and check whether the portfolio is above_threshold etc. and thus find 100 matches.

When looking for the top 30 portfolios, however, this aproach is no longer feasible. The DBMS must read all portfolio rows instead, filter them and sort them to get the top 30, before it can get to the portfolio_res. And obviously it is slow to get the top 30 rows.

This is not that surprising, because sorting can be a costly process, especially when it comes to sorting a large amount of rows.

All you can do about this is help the DBMS by providing an appropriate index, so it can get the result relatively fast. In PostgreSQL you can provide a partial index only containing the rows in question. With `end_portfolio_value` as the first column in the index, the index gets sorted by this column, so you'll get the top 30 quickly. I even add the ID, which we can directly use to get to the `portfolio_res` table

```
create index idx on portfolio (end_portfolio_value desc, id)
  where (above_threshold and backtest_id = 1 and end_portfolio_value > 2);
```

Optimally, there should of course also be an index on portfolio_res(portfolio_id) in your database, too.

Comment: would having the `index on portfolio_res(portfolio_id)` be enough? My queries will always subset `portfolio` table first. Then find the corresponding rows from `portfolio_res`. I will most likely never go the other way around ( because `portfolio_res` will always be massive ). is a foreign key not enough to subset `portfolio_res` by `portfolio_id` quickly?

Comment: As mentioned: you don't decide this; the DBMS does. And your first query was so quick, because the DBMS decided not to start with `portfolio`, but with `portfolio_res`. I assumed the second query to be so slow because of the sorting process, but reading your request again, you may be right. The sorting doesn't take that long. I would have thought you have an index on `portfolio_res(portfolio_id)` already as this is a foreign key. These have an index usually, but sometimes they don't. Well, just try. Add that index and look at the execution plan.